# Generate a nested list of all posts, sorted first by year, then by month

Tags: list

```
<ul>
    <li>2011
        <ul>
            <li>January
                <ul>
                    <li>Post 1</li>
                    <li>Post 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>February
                <ul>
                    <li>etc</li>
                    <li>etc</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-archive-by-month-and-then-post-by-post and here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-date-format-using-post_date?replies=10 might get you started